# SQL Server 2008 R2 won't start - times out

Tags: sql-server

I can no longer start or stop SQL Express.  This only happened AFTER installing SQL management studio the other day. One of the parameters tells me that it is not running under a 64 bit operating system. - Well it is!

What can I do?

This is the log file report:

```
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64) 
    Apr 22 2011 19:23:43 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      All rights reserved.
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      Server process ID is 5028.
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.', System Model: 'GA-880GM-USB3'.
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 3688 at 30/10/2012 10:46:25 (local) 30/10/2012 10:46:25 (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      Error: 17113, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      Error 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100) occurred while opening file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them if necessary.
```

Comment: Is the master.mdf file in the location stated in the error log (last line) you posted? If not, find it and put it there. Depending on what else is missing, you'll need mastlog.ldf, msdb.mdf, msdb.ldf, model.mdf, and model.ldf.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon this line in your error log:

```
2012-10-30 10:47:27.09 Server      Error 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100) occurred while opening file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf'
```

This means that the master database is no longer where SQL Server is expecting it. Did the file move or get deleted?

Can you do a search for **master.mdf** on your server?

If you find it, either copy it back to the path listed in the error log, or update SQL Server Configuration manager to point to the correct location.

Once you fix this error, you will probably receive an error on master.ldf as well. The solution will be the same.

Then, you will probably have to deal with **tempdb**, **model**, and **msdb**. Those can be solved in a similar fashion.

When you get to these, another thing to explore is starting SQL from the command line with trace flag 3608. This will allow you to correct each database one at a time.

Here are some links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180965(v=sql.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx

First take care of master, and then let us know how the rest of it goes.

Good luck!